# How to remove tree node and move its node node upwards?

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

Actually in my treeview ,when i remove a tree node it removes all its child node, But i need to move its child node upwards instead of removing .I have to use in winforms in c sharp.

Anybody help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What Rhapsody said.
And here is an example:

```
if (tree.Nodes.Contains(theNode))
        {
            TreeNodeCollection childNodes = theNode.Nodes;
            tree.Nodes.Remove(theNode);
            foreach (TreeNode child in childNodes)
            {
                tree.Nodes.Add(child);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Doesn't that add the nodes onto the end of the list, rather than where the parent node was?

Comment: @Stuart Yes they are added at the end. I don't know if by "move its child node upwards" he meant to add them in the place of parent node or move them up in the tree rank

Answer (score 4):

So you just want to remove a node and keep any childnodes?

What you have to do is:

1. Remove childnodes from the node you want to delete.
2. Add childnodes before the node you want to delete.
3. Remove the selected node.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're having is caused by the fact that the child nodes of any given node is stored in `myNode.Nodes`. So, when you remove a node all of its nodes are freed as well, so you will have to first iterate through the child nodes, move them, then remove the original node:

```
//assume treeChild is what you are removing, and treeControl is you TreeView
//this code will move all of its children nodes
//to be children of its parent before being removed

//set that we are updating the treeview control
//increases performance by blocking the paint methods until update is finished
treeControl.BeginUpdate();

//this will loop through child nodes of what we are removing
//then add them to the parent
foreach(TreeView node in treeChild.ChildNodes)
{
   node.Parent.Nodes.Add(node);
}

//then remove the node
treeChild.Remove();

treeControl.EndUpdate(); //note that we finished updated the controls
```

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through the child nodes and add them to the node's parent before removing the node itself. This code should handle cases where the node to be removed is a parent node.

```
if (nodeToRemove.Nodes.Count > 0) {
List<TreeNode> childNodes = new List<TreeNode>();
foreach (TreeNode n in nodeToRemove.Nodes) {
   childNodes.Add(n);
}
if ((nodeToRemove.Parent != null)) {
   nodeToRemove.Parent.Nodes.AddRange(childNodes.ToArray());
   } else {
     nodeToRemove.TreeView.Nodes.AddRange(childNodes.ToArray());
    }
   }
nodeToRemove.Remove();
```